# Getting ID of a Neighbour Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I learned that you can get the parentElement of a srcElement that triggers a javascript function call using this:

```
    function selectThis() {
        var cbID = event.srcElement.id;
        var lblID = event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.id;
    }
```

where the elements are nested like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" >
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" onClick="selectThis()"/>
</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbx1" runat="server" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
```

But is there a way to get the ID of the textbox below the label? Is there a "neighbourElement" type of thing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling

Comment: Don't use `srcElement` it's not standard and won't work in firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement
Use `target` or `currentTarget` based on your needs.

Comment: You can use Node.closest() to find the nearest textarea. `event.srcElement.closest('textarea').getAttribute('id')` should work. It is supported in a large number of browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=closest

Answer (score 2):

```
event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling
```

You might need to add one more .parentElement (or 1 less) but that will return the element directly after the parent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well try .NextSibling.
BTW I would recommend you to use jquery for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSFiddle for you - using similar markup. https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/x1uqes9p/

```
var cb = document.querySelector('#checkbox1');

cb.onchange = function(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.value = "Woot"
}
```

In this example, when you check the checkbox it uses `e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling` to set the value on the textarea.

Good luck.